# xlsxwriter: How to use another module to write into worksheet created in main code

Tags: python, excel, module, xlsxwriter

I was curious if there was a way to use another module to write into an excel worksheet made in the main code. So for example, I have the following code that creates the excel file:

```
# Package
import xlsxwriter

# Module for this code
import excel_edit

# Main Code
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')    
sheet_1 = workbook.add_worksheet               

excel_edit.write_sheet(sheet_1, list)  # Function taken from excel_edit module

workbook.close()
```

And here is the code for the module:

```
import xlsxwriter

def write_sheet(worksheet, list)
    # Create label
    worksheet.write(0, 0, 'Time (sec)

    # Code here to loop and add list elements row by row
```

When I run this, the excel file isn't being created at all and from what I discovered the `import xlsxwriter` in my `excel_edit` module isn't actually being used. Is there a way to still do this method, or should I just shove all the code into main lol.

Answer (score 1):

This calls your function from other module as expected:

```
import xlsxwriter
import excel_edit

alist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
sheet_1 = workbook.add_worksheet()
excel_edit.write_sheet(sheet_1, alist)
workbook.close()
```

Note the `()` in `workbook.add_worksheet`
You need to call this function, else you pass the function itself to `excel_edit.write_sheet`